# What is a "pressure cup" copper fitting?

Tags: plumbing, terminology

**Pressure cup** is not a term I encountered when I was last searching for copper fittings, about ten years ago for a bathroom remodel. Is pressure cup a synonym for tapered thread which needs to be tightened, or does it refer to the depth of the solder section for residential and commercial water applications where the water from the mains is under pressure?

P.S. I have found a document that says it refers to a deeper solder depth,  for pressurized systems.

[image: Pressure Cup Fitting]

Comment: You may not have come across it 10 years ago, but something's brought it to your attention very recently. Care to include the context in which you found it now? That may help get you a better answer more quickly.

Comment: Saw it online as part of the product description when searching for fittings on the website of one of the big box stores.

Comment: Might be worth including a link and/or picture. I'm not a plumber, so I haven't a clue what it even looks like, though it might be obvious to a plumber.

Comment: crimpable o-ring sealed copper fittings have come to general availability in the past decade. might be a term for those. they are popular with plumbers as being quick, flameless, and involving expensive tools that homeowners have a hard time justifying, but which pay off quickly for pros, and scare most homeowners off making modifications themselves. but most search results seem to indicate simply a term for solder sockets (female) on pressure (as opposed to DWV) pipe fittings.

Comment: To me, that simply looks like a solder x thread adapter...

Answer (score 1):

The terms "pressure" and "cup" are not related. Pressure means the fitting is designed for copper pipe under pressure. And cup or "C" means it receives a pipe or fitting "Ftg."